# Trouble injecting defined parameters into constructor using PHP-DI

Tags: php, dependency-injection, constructor, php-di

This may seen rudimentary but I cant seem to directly inject any parameters into my class constructor without using annotations. Below is definition made and the class called

```
    $shell->set('root','[Root Definition Here]');

    $shell->make('Namespace\To\Product');

    Class Product{

          public function __construct($root){
               //coding continues here
          }
    }
```

But I keep getting this error

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Entry
>   "Namespace\To\Product" cannot be resolved:
>   Parameter $root of __construct() has no value defined or guessable

However this issue will be resolved if I use annotations. But I really want not to resort to annotations each time I'm injecting parameters.

Whats the issue here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP-DI injects using the type-hints, not the parameter names. So it would work if `$root` had a type-hint (e.g. `Foo\Bar $root`), but as it is now it can't work.

You have to define the parameter manually:

```
$container->set(
    'Namespace\To\Product',
    DI\object()->constructor(DI\get('root')
);
```

Comment: Ok got it but my classes are being loaded on the fly, will see how wildcards can be used here. Thanks